# How do I pull a list from XML into a master-detail list?

Tags: ios, objective-c, master-detail

I want to show a simple list of image titles, then be able to touch each and see the image. The list is in an XML doc with title, URL, and unique integer identifier for each image.

Comment: Can you use JSON instead? It is **much** faster and easier to use.

Comment: Parse the xml, then load the titles in the master view in the tableview. On selecting a row, display the image in the detailed view using an UIImageView. I am not sure what your issue is. What have you tried and what is not working?

Answer (score 0):

I found this excellent tutorial by Rafael Garcia for anyone who has the same problem. Still working out the logic of it so I can adapt it to my project, but I've copied his code and got a working prototype.

http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/